# Prevent geom_smooth from passing weights argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I am trying to pass a `method` to `geom_smooth`, that I don't think is officially supported -- `expectreg.ls` from the [`expectreg`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expectreg/vignettes/expectreg.pdf) package. As required, returned objects from `expectreg` do have a `predict` method.

However, I think that `geom_smooth` tries to pass a `weights` argument to the method supplied, and since expectile regression depends on an IRWLS type algorithm, I think that supplying an external `weights` argument doesn't make sense, and as such is not a formal argument of `expectreg.ls`. In any case, this fails with a:

```
Error in method(formula, data = data, weights = weight, ...) : 
  unused argument (weights = weight)
```

I also tried modifying the `expectreg.ls` function definition to add a dummy `weights` argument, but then `ggplot2` complains that:

```
Error: geom_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

At this point, I have decided to ask for help. Is there an easy way to get `geom_smooth` to work with `expectreg.ls` without creating the predictions beforehand?

---

Here is some code to test solutions on:

```
dfX = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(dfX, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "expectreg.ls", se = FALSE, aes(color = "Expectile Regression (alpha = 0.1)"), expectiles = 0.1)
```

Comment: Rather late but have you try to override adding ```method.args = list(weights=NULL)``` to you geom_smooth call.